# Python - Dynamic processing in parallel based on a list

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to create approach to run multiple queries from a list at the same time, for that I am using threading library. For that I have this code:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
queries = ["SELECT * FROM db1.trans", "SELECT * FROM db1.order", "SELECT * FROM db2.Store", "SELECT * FROM db2.Document", "SELECT * FROM db3.Sales"]
class DatabaseWorker(Thread):
    __lock = Lock()

    def __init__(self, query, result_queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.query = query
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self):
        result = None
        print("Connecting to database...")
        try:
            conn = connect(host=host, port=port)
            curs = conn.cursor()
            curs.execute(self.query)
            result = curs
            curs.close()
            conn.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
        self.result_queue.append(result)

delay = 1
result_queue = []
for query in queries:
    worker1 = DatabaseWorker(query,result_queue)

worker1.start()
while len(result_queue) < 2:
    time.sleep(delay)
job_done = True
worker1.join()
```

Using the above approach I am running in sequential mode. I know I can do in this way:

```
worker1 = DatabaseWorker(queries[0],result_queue)
worker2 = DatabaseWorker(queries[1],result_queue)
...
```

But I think it is not the best way. Anyone knows how can I run all the queries from the list in a dynamic mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python threading is not really parallel because of the Python GIL (Global Interpreter Lock).

For real multiprocessing parallel operations you can use the Python multiprocessing module.

example :

```
import multiprocessing

def runner(task):
    return f'Hi, i do {task}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_tasks = ['1', '2', '3']
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        result = pool.map(runner, list_tasks)
    print(result)
```